# Чем новация отличается от инновации?

Tags: орфоэпия

Чем *новация* отличается от *инновации*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У этих слов разный набор значений. В значении "новшество" они синонимичны (хотя стилистичеки немного различаются), в осталных значения - полностью различны.

*НОВАЦИЯ, -и; ж. [от лат. novatio - обновление, изменение] Книжн.

1.

Новшество, нововведение. Полезная, вредная н. Литературные, музыкальные новации. Н. в технике. Природа не терпит всевозможных новаций, она консервативна.

2. Юрид.

Прекращение ранее принятых обязательств с принятием новых. Н. договора.

ИННОВАЦИЯ, -и; ж.

1. Книжн.

Нововведение, новшество. Инновации в управлении, политике. 

2. Экон.
Комплекс мероприятий, направленных на внедрение в экономику новой техники, технологий, изобретений и т.п.; модернизация. Экономические инновации. Фонд инноваций.

3. Лингв.  

Новое, более позднее явление в языке. Инновации в лексике. < Инновационный, -ая, -ое. И. процесс. И. банк  (банк, финансирующий новые направления в науке и технике).*

©Кузнецов.